# Default button overrides the enter in a rich text control

Tags: asp.net, rich-text-editor, defaultbutton

I have page with a default button assigned. However when I hit enter in a TextBox with Ajax:HtmlEditorExtendor, the form will be submitted. Is it a bug in Ajax? Is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your target control might be a single line textbox. Try setting the property for TextMode="MultiLine" on the textbox you're targeting for the html editor to see if that makes a difference.